# Serving Compiled Scripts on Webserver

Tags: java, apache, intellij-idea, ide, webserver

I have a webserver running Apache http webserver and it works fine. I can view/download the files I put in the htdocs folder through a web browser.

What I want to be able to do is write Java code in my IDE (using IntelliJ IDEA) and when I compile my project, I want the updated compiled class files to be automatically available on my webserver for download. Currently I am using a PHP script to retrieve the files from my project directory to download them but I want to change this so that the URL points to the actual file and has a .class extension. I need to do this because I plan to load the classes using a classloader in the future. I do not want to manually copy the files from my project folder to the htdocs folder every time I compile.

I've thought of some ways to do this but they aren't ideal:

1. I could use some program that syncs files between two folders and have my project folder sync the class files to the htdocs folder. I don't really want to rely on another program and this just seems like the wrong way to do it.
2. Create a VirtualHost on my webserver and have the project folder as a subdomain. This doesn't seem like that bad of an option but I don't really want to create a sub domain just for the class files.
3. Change the compiler output path in my IDE to the htdocs folder. This would work but I need to keep the original output path because it is automatically backed up by my Google Drive. It would be good if I could specify an additional compiler output directory in IntelliJ and then have it compile to the default directory as well as the htdocs directory but as far as I can tell this is not possible with IntelliJ.

Are there any other options that I'm missing? What is typically done in this situation if anything? I'm leaning towards trying option #2.

Thanks.

Comment: Depending on what build system you're using, you should be able to add a copy target and have the copy happen automatically when you build. I know IntelliJ supports Ant and Gradle and it would be trivial to add the copy target to these.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I went with symlinks because I don't have experience with Ant or Gradle and also because symlinks fits my needs more. I should have included in the OP that I plan to be working on the project on different computers other than the computer that is hosting the webserver so a syncing option seems like the best for me. I have the project folder synced between computers via Google Drive and then the project folder is synced with the htdocs folder via symlinks on the webserver computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating a symlink to your compiled code dir in your served Dir.

Comment: Thank you. I went with this and it works perfectly as far as I can see. I had no idea symlinks were even a thing.

Comment: No problem. Just be careful with your permissions.